# Javascript code to add captha to google forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, captcha, google-forms

I want to add javascript code that does the work of protecting google forms from spam.
The logic is that

var a = random number from 1 to 1000;
var b = random number from 1 to 1000;
var c = input by the user;

Condition if `var c = var a + var b` then only submit the form or else show error.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not what you want, just using SimpleCaptcha might be better in all honesty. What you want to do is much easier to have a computer solve, since it's just maths. [Here's SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/)